# Filtering arrays in Dart

Tags: dart, object, filtering

Can anyone guide me and tell me where I am making mistake in the code.
I want to filter all the food which have Pizzatype veggie.
I am getting an empty array in the output.

Comment: Your condition, `pizzaList.contains(PizzaType.veggie)`, is wrong: It just checks whether *any* pizza equaling the type exists in the list and thus always returns the same value (presumably false, because Pizzas don't equal PizzaTypes due to type mismatch alone).

Comment: Please provide your `Pizza` class

Comment: Have you taken the tour yet? As to formatting: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: yes i tried but says "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." is there any other way i can share my code?

Answer (score 2):

[where](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/dart-core/Iterable/where.html) iterates one pizza at a time. Something like this might work.

```
final findVeggiePizza = pizzaList.where((pizza) =>  pizza.type == PizzaType.veggie).toList();
```

Comment: I got an error at pizza.type.

Comment: @Luisa: You haven't provided your Pizza class, so we can't tell how the type can be obtained. Is there a variable or a getter named `type`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably as so

```
enum PizzaType {
  veggie,
  meatLover
}


class PizzaWithToppings {
  String typeDes;
  int price;
  List list;
  PizzaType type;

  PizzaWithToppings(this.typeDes, this.price, this.list, this.type);
  
  bool filter(PizzaType type) {
    return this.type == type;
  }
  
}


void main() {

    final pizzaWithToppings =
      PizzaWithToppings('Mushroom Pizza', 12, [1, 2, 3], PizzaType.veggie);
  
     final pizzaWithToppings2 =
      PizzaWithToppings('Chiken Pizza', 20, [1, 2, 3], PizzaType.meatLover);
  
    final pizzaWithToppings3 =
      PizzaWithToppings('Veggie Pizza', 15, [1, 2, 3], PizzaType.veggie);
  
    final pizzaList = [pizzaWithToppings, pizzaWithToppings2,pizzaWithToppings3];
        
    final findVeggiePizza = pizzaList.where((pizza) =>  pizza.filter(PizzaType.veggie)).toList();
  
    print (findVeggiePizza);
}
```

Is that so?